# How to create a two or more Color Custom QPushButton in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

How to Create a Custom Button with two or More color text and as well as in With double or single underline(in a particular letter)? I tried my level best. But the Blank button (no text) only appears.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MyButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__ (self, mytext,parent=None):
        super(MyButton,self).__init__()
        self.mytext = mytext


        def paintEvent(self, event):
            document = QTextDocument()
            document.setDocumentMargin(0)
            document.setHtml(mytext)

            mypixmap=QPixmap(document.size().tosize())
            mypixmap.fill(Qt.transparent)
            painter = QPainter(mypixmap)
            document.drawContents(painter)
            painter.end()

class CustomButton(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Grid layout Example")
        self.setGeometry(100,100,400,400)
        self.widget()
        self.show()

    def widget(self):
        self.btn_sample = MyButton(QIcon("<h2><i>My sample</i> <font color=red>Button!</font></h2>"))
        self.btn_sample.resize(20,20)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_sample)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = CustomButton()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why is that `paintEvent` function at that indentation level? What do you expect it to do, *there*?

Comment: I think If We make Qicon then we need PaintEvent and through Googling saw a lot of examples with paintevent only.  @ musicamante

Comment: 1. QIcon has nothing to do with that; 2. Yes, you should override paintEvent, but not like that, and not at that indentation level (which makes it completely useless). I suggest you to study and understand all those examples you've mentioned, as you're clearly trying to "patch" things you found without understanding any of it. Start from simple examples, study what they do, search for the documentation of **all** their functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, Text, parent = None):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__()

        mydocument = QTextDocument()
        mydocument.setDocumentMargin(0)
        mydocument.setHtml(Text)

        mypixmap = QPixmap(mydocument.size().toSize())
        mypixmap.fill(Qt.transparent)
        mypainter = QPainter(mypixmap)
        mydocument.drawContents(mypainter)
        mypainter.end()

        myicon = QIcon(mypixmap)
        self.setIcon(myicon)
        self.setIconSize(mypixmap.size())

class mainwindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self , parent = None):
        super(mainwindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupgui()
    def setupgui(self):
        self.resize(800,600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Custom Button With two Color Text')
        newLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.dashboard = MyButton("<h2><i>Dash Board</i> <font color=red>Qt!</font></h2>",self)
        self.transcation = MyButton('<font color="red"><u>T</u></font><font color="black">ranscation</font>',self)
        newLayout.addWidget(self.dashboard)
        newLayout.addWidget(self.transcation)
        self.setLayout(newLayout)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = mainwindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]